# How to print out an ArrayList<Integer> in a HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java

How do you printout an index of type HashSet>?

Here is the code:

```
HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> possibleRoutes;
```

I tried

```
int indexOfMinDistance = routesDistances.indexOf(Collections.min(routesDistances));
System.out.println(possibleRoutes.indexOf(indexOfMinDistance));
```

The programme suggests to cast possibleRoutes to List which produces more errors to the problem because they are not of the same type. So how do you print out an index, eg. an `ArrayList<Integer>, of a HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>?`

Comment: Your question is not clear at all.  Do you need to iterate through your set?

Comment: Well, what I need is to print out an one of the ArrayList<Integer> in a HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>.

Comment: OK. What stops you? Do you know how to find the one you need?

Comment: System.out.println(possibleRoutes.indexOf(indexOfMinDistance)) does not work. The error is: "The method indexOf(int) is undefined for the type HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>" and I have no idea how to fix this..

Comment: This is still gibberish. Do you know what [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is?

Comment: A `Set` doesn't have indexes, unless it is a `SortedSet`, which a `HashSet` isn't.

Comment: Let's say the name of the HashSet is possibleRoutes. Now, if you want to print out the first element, which would have the index number 0, how should you do it?

Comment: Ok. My HashSet has four lists of type ArrayList<Integer>. Now I want to print out one of the array lists. This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using a HashSet?

Comment: There is no first element.  Things in sets don't have index numbers.  They're not in any order.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking how to iterate the hashset this might help you..

```
  HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> possibleRoutes = new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();

  Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> possList  =possibleRoutes.iterator();

  /* here u can't take out by index, hasset 
    makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set*/

  ArrayList<Integer>main = possList.next();  //but can loop through it by next which gives ArrayList<integer>
  for(Integer m : main)
 { System.out.println(m); }
```